# Can i add multiple certbot emails for notification?

Tags: linux, certbot

I have searched the official documentation and I have not obtained a response, it is possible to have, for example, two email addresses for CERTBOT notifications, to know when a certificate is about to expire?

I have only been able to configure one at a time

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Yes, you can add multiple email addresses

---

From [`certbot --help all`](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html?highlight=email#certbot-command-line-options):

> `-m EMAIL` / `--email EMAIL`
>
> Email used for registration and recovery contact.
>
> **Use comma to register multiple emails**, ex:
> u1@example.com,u2@example.com. (default: Ask).

---

This feature has been added in [pull request #5994](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/pull/5994) after being brought to attention by [issue #4242](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/4242)